# Why does QueryPerformanceCounter/QueryPerformanceFrequency fail?

Tags: windows, performancecounter

There is an article on MSDN talking about `QueryPerformanceCounter`:

> [Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx)

Towards the bottom is an FAQ section with an interesting question:

> **Under what circumstances does QueryPerformanceFrequency return FALSE, or QueryPerformanceCounter return zero?**
>
> > This won't occur on any system that runs Windows XP or later.

That answer is correct, except that it is wrong. There **are** circumstances where QueryPerformanceFrequency will return `false`.

I will be self answering this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Under what circumstances does QueryPerformanceFrequency return FALSE, or QueryPerformanceCounter return zero?**
>
> This won't occur on any system that runs Windows XP or later.

That is correct, perhaps with the slight change in phrasing:

> This **can** occur on any system that runs Windows XP or later.

There are circumstances where `QueryPerformanceFrequency` returns **false**. You can Google for people experiencing the problem.

i had the problem today (on Windows 7):

```
Int64 freq;
//...
QueryPerformanceFrequency(@freq);
```

The function call fails (returns **false**), and `GetLastError` returns:

```
ERROR_NOACCESS
   998 (0x3E6)
   Invalid access to memory location.
```

### Alignment Matters

The issue happens if your `Int64` memory address is not *double-word* (4-byte) aligned. For example, if you use a compiler that defaults to `Byte` or `Word` alignment for objects, or structures, or class member variables. In this case, `QueryPerformanceCounter` will return false.

**Note**: It's entirely possible that `QueryPerformanceCounter` only ***happens*** to work with *double-word* (4-byte) alignment, and [might actually require *quad-word* (8-byte) alignment](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip75.htm). The [Windows x64 calling convention documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) is silent on the subject.

It is also possible that [the CPU hardware is silently fixing up 4-byte alignment to 8-byte alignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290049%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#ia64alignment_topic4), where it won't do the same for 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, or 7 byte alignment. It is also possible that this new drive system, if operable, could render the Red October undetectable to our SOSUS warning nets in the Atlantic.

## tl;dr

> **Under what circumstances does QueryPerformanceFrequency return FALSE, or QueryPerformanceCounter return zero?**

The function can fail with error code `ERROR_NOACCESS` (Invalid access to memory location) if the variable to not *double-word* (8-byte) aligned.

### Bonus Chatter

The documentation:

> ### Return value
>
> If the installed hardware supports a high-resolution performance counter, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx). On systems that run Windows XP or later, the function will always succeed and will thus never return zero.